# Obtain Type of object in gridview rows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAgencyName" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="212px" OnPageIndexChanging="gvAgencyName_PageIndexChanging">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#494949"></HeaderStyle>
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="1%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxHeader1" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbx" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need a Javascript which will return the type of the object and its status(In case of checkbox), wether its checked or unchecked.
Please Help..

Comment: Do have tried any thing?

Comment: In javascript at where I mean in function, or onclick event of something do you want status of checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom validator and using the following method I was able to get the type of the checkbox.

```
        function CheckRequiredData(sender, args) {
        var cell;
        var grid = document.getElementById("MainContent_Gridname");
        if (grid.rows.length <= 0) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }

        else if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
            for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
                cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];
                for (j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                    if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```